# How to create a MySQL table in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a cars table in MySQL, here is my code:

```
<?php

$sql = "CREATE TABLE cars (
    regnr varchar(10),
    make varchar(30),
    yearmodel int,
    mileage int
)";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    echo '<p>Table created</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Failed: check the sql: ';
    echo $sql;
}

?>
```

But it resulted in an error:

```
Connection ok
Failed: check the sql: CREATE TABLE cars ( regnr varchar(10), make varchar(30), yearmodel int, mileage int)
```

How can I make this code works?

Comment: You're not setting `$connection` in this script. Are you including it?

Comment: Try showing the actual error - `mysqli_error($connection);` to see why it failed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah I have included it in another file this is a snippet without the code include 'test1.php'

Comment: @NigelRen It says that No database selected

Comment: Then your problem is in your connection. You should always specify a database.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this. Replace `_DATABASE_` with the name of the database you want to create the table in

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE _DATABASE_.cars (
    regnr varchar(10),
    make varchar(30),
    yearmodel int,
    mileage int
)";
```